# Is there a way to set/turn off some of the Angular lint functionality of VS Code?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I like the "lint" functionality of VSCode with Angular 4 but there are a few things I'd like to turn off.  Is that something that can be done in a preference file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your project is an Angular CLI project, then it will be configured to use TSLint, which you can configure by editing the `tslint.json` file.

You can find more info regarding how to set the configuration in the related TSLint documentation: https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/configuration/

Answer (score 0):

The linting is likely coming for a tslint.json file. You can find documentation of the rules [here](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/). Adjust the rules to your liking.